# How to do curve stitching?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, software-recommendation

How would one go about making something like this in Illustrator or other software? I know how to make a circle and lines but is there an easy way to do the spacing and connection?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assumed that would be a continuous path moving from one point to the next (as you mentioned stitching) but it looks like they are actually just a bunch of squares and triangles, rotated around a common center. In which case...

1. Draw a sqaure:

[image: Square]

2. Use a transform effect (Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform... ) with a rotation and a number of copies:

[image: Transform]

3. Draw a triangle inside the "circle" of your transformed sqaures:

[image: Triangle]

4. You want to rotate your triangles around the same center but the center of your triangle isn't the same as the center of your squares so draw a circle with no stroke or fill and center it with the sqaures, then group it with your triangle.

   Then apply a transform effect as you did with the sqaure:

[image: Transform]

[image: Finished]

Comment: Even continuous stiching would work the same way just with a different number of points and youd rotate a line.

Comment: Wow, awesome! I never would have thought to use whole shapes.